# Двоеточие или запятая между частями предложения

Tags: запятые, двоеточие

*Только одно отличает героев от безумцев () побеждают ли они или проигрывают.*

Какой знак поставить в скобках, двоеточие или запятую? Можно ли поставить тире?

Comment: «Побеждают ли они или...». Лишнее «ли». Одно из двух: они побеждают или проигрывают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если есть два предложения А и Б, и в предложении А что-то обозначается словом или сочетанием, а в предложении Б обозначенное в предложении А словом или сочетанием более подробно раскрывается, то в таких ситуациях между А и Б ставится двоеточие, даже если между предложениями есть союзные слова.

**Примеры без союзных слов между предложениями:**
Погода была ужасная: ветер выл, мокрый снег падал хлопьями. ( В первом предложении обозначает ‟ ужасность ” словом ‟ ужасно ”, а во втором предложении эта ‟ ужасность ” раскрывается более подробно. )
Страшная мысль мелькнула в уме моем: я вообразил её в руках разбойников. ( В первом предложении кое-что обозначается словом ‟ мысль ”, а последующем обозначенное словом ‟ мысль ” раскрывается. )

**Примеры с союзными словами:**
И, сделав это, почувствовал, что результат получился желаемый: что он тронут и она тронута. ( Обозначенное сочетанием ‟ желаемый результат ” в первом предложении раскрывается во втором предложении. )
Я боюсь одного: чтобы переутомление наших людей не отразилось на их работе по уходу за ранеными. ( В первом что-то обозначается словом ‟ одного ”, а во втором обозначенное словом ‟ одного ” раскрывается. )

**Правильная пунктуация следующая**: ‟ Только одно отличает героев от безумцев: побеждают ли они или проигрывают ”.